# nginx returning malformed packet/no response with 200 when request body is large

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, malformed

I've hosted my Django rest framework API server with `gunicorn` behind the `nginx`. When I'm hitting the API to the `nginx` with a small body in the request, the response comes. But, with a large payload, it returns nothing with 200 OK response.

However, when I hit the `gunicorn` directly, it returns a proper response.

NGNIX is messing up with the response if the request payload is large.

I captured packets via `tcpdump`, there it is showing that the response contains `MALFORMED PACKET`. Following is the TCP dump:

```
[Malformed Packet: JSON]
[Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
    [Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)]
    [Severity level: Error]
    [Group: Malformed]
```

NGINX config :

```
  server {
listen 6678  backlog=10000;
client_body_timeout 180s;

location / {
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_read_timeout 120s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 120s;

  proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000;
  proxy_redirect    default;
}
}
```

I've never seen NGINX playing hard on me. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If nginx and gunicorn are running on the same server, rather than using a loopback for the two to talk to each other, a unix socket is a bit more performant I believe. I can't tell if you already doing that from the config snippet. The only other thing I'm seeing from the gunicorn deploy [docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) that might be helpful here is `client_max_body_size 4G;`, which according to the nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) defaults to 1 MB.